# Software interrupts in C?

Tags: c, linux, windows, interrupt, isr

I have understand the concepts of software interrupt and hardware interrupts theoretically but anyone could give me an example for software interrupt and explain it ?? Please it would be a great help for me.

C program example for windows or Linux operating system

Comment: An example is given in the 3rd paragraph here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth : I understand the theoretical concept . Could you please explain me with c program example ??

Comment: Such interrupts are handled by the OS and drivers.  There is not going to be any sensibly-postable example.  Linux open-source - go look at some drivers.

Comment: @user2984410 - An analogy - You (the computer) is thinking. The interrupt is an idiot has poked you in the ribs with a pencil. You stop what you are doing and shout an expletive. that is an interrupt

Comment: There are some compilers for embedded systems that have extensions for `C` to handle interrupts, but, as others have pointed out, these are not applicable for Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 3):

[Interrupts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) are [handled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt_handler) by the operating system [kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28computing%29). Applications don't see them (because the kernel processes all interrupts so hides them from applications). On [Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel), application [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) see [signals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal). See [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Notice that the [C11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29) standard (on the C programming language) don't know about interrupts.

Please understand that signals are not interrupts (and Linux applications don't see directly any interrupts, except by measuring them thru [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), see file `/proc/interrupts`). And signal handlers have strong restrictions: only *async-signal-safe functions* ca be called (directly or indirectly) from a signal handler. Often, setting a `volatile sig_atomic_t` flag is sensible in your signal handler, and your application should test it elsewhere.

If you have an [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (e.g. around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) etc...) using the Linux specific [signalfd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html) could be very convenient.

So when programming a Linux application (and probably also a Windows one) you don't care about interrupts (but you might handle some signals). BTW, a Linux kernel typically sees hundreds (or perhaps thousands) of interrupts each second, and wake up some driver and/or reschedule some task for most of them. A given Linux application process usually handles much less than one signal per second (but YMMV).